# Xamarin.Android - Styling does not apply on TouchWiz

Tags: android, button, xamarin.android, styles

I have an Android app using a style based off of the android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar style.

I've created a few button styles, and they all apply and look fine on my device (G901F - running RR 5.8; Nougat).
However, on my colleague's device (I9515 - running stock TWiz; Lollipop) the buttons are blue, while all the other styles were applied correctly.

I've attempted using Support.V7 to apply the theme, however that doesn't seem to work, either.

Here is the Styles.xml containing the themes used in the apps.
The only button theme working, is Button_WhiteText, as the text on all buttons is (almost) white, as declared in colors.xml.

```
<style name="KrebsTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary_colour</item>

    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/statusbar_colour</item>

    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent_colour</item>

</style>

<style name="Button_WhiteText" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/almost_white</item>

</style>

<style name="Button_StoreItem" parent="Button_WhiteText">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/item_store_colour</item>

</style>

<style name="Button_OutsourceItem" parent="Button_WhiteText">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/item_outsource_colour</item>

</style>

<style name="Button_TransferItem" parent="Button_WhiteText">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/item_transfer_colour</item>

</style>

<style name="Button_CommissionItems" parent="Button_WhiteText">
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/item_commission_colour</item>

</style>
```

Is this a common phenomenon with TouchWiz devices?
Are there known workarounds, or is it simply something I've misunderstood about theming?

Comment: Did you have any information about this? I need to customize the touchwiz calendar in a xamarin application and I can't find any information

Comment: If I remember correctly, I updated the AppCompat library, and then it worked.
But ultimately, I switched to Java completely, because Xamarin simply didn't provide what I needed.